# Ionic 4 Custom Icons have black outline when Imported

Tags: icons, ionic4

I'm importing a few custom icons into my Ionic 4 project and although I have managed to successfully import the icons, they are imported with a black outline. I have checked the SVG file / Actual File to Edit SVG and the only thing in there is the Icon itself. Not the Black Outline.

I have tried `no-border` as well as clear yet the border just doesn't seem to want to leave.

icon output:

[image]

ion-icon code:

[image]

Comment: I have this same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this ?